# Lambda Expression For Getmany is not filtering in unit testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, nunit, moq

I am using a lambda expression for GetMany() in repository method to filter some values from large number of values. it is working fine in Mvc code. but when i wrote the unit test i made a mock for the repository and given the setup   as given below

```
focusRepository.Setup(x => x.GetMany(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Focus, bool>>>())).Returns(fakeFocus);
```

But this is not working. it s not filtering the values. Instead it returns either null or all the values.
The whole Test method is

```
  IEnumerable<Focus> fakeFocus = new List<Focus> 
        {
        new Focus { FocusId = 1, FocusName="Test1",GroupId = 1},
         new Focus { FocusId = 2, FocusName="Test2",GroupId = 1},
        new Focus { FocusId = 3, FocusName="Test3",GroupId = 2}
      }.AsEnumerable();
        focusRepository.Setup(x => x.GetMany(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Focus, bool>>>())).Returns(fakeFocus);

        GroupGoalFormModel goal = new GroupGoalFormModel();
        GroupController controller = new GroupController();

        ViewResult result = controller.CreateGoal(2) as ViewResult;

        Assert.IsNotNull(result, "View Result is null");
        Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(GroupGoalFormModel),
            result.ViewData.Model, "Wrong View Model");
```

In my repository i wrote the code as

```
 IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
```

Can any one please help me

Comment: Can you show your whole test method?

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the exact result that your method should return, no matter with which parameters it's called. So of course your method is always returning the same result.

The `Repository` should have it's own tests where you check if the correct results are returned for each filter. When testing the `Controller`, you mock the `Repository` and hard code the results.

Comment: You will always get the same results because you hardcoded the result. Your Mock won't filter the list of Focus